# Print n-array tree from parent array

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, tree

I need to write a recursive algorithm to pretty print an n-array tree with the parent array given.

This is my code:

```
   int pretty_print_r1(int* parent, int i, int indent, int target, int size)
   {
    if (i > size) return NULL;
    if (parent[i] != target)
    {
        pretty_print_r1(parent, i + 1, indent, target, size);
    }
    else {
        if (indent)
            for (int i = 0; i < indent; i++)
                printf(" ");
        printf("%d\n", i + 1);
        pretty_print_r1(parent, 0, indent + 4, i+1, size);
    }
   }
int main()
{
    int parinti[] = { 2, 7, 5, 2, 7, 7, -1, 5, 2 };
   
    pretty_print_r1(parinti, 0, 0, -1, 9);
}
```

The target is the parent you need to search in the array but it only selects one of each and stops. Do you have an idea on how to solve it?

This is the expected output:

```
7
    2
        1
        4
        9
    5
        3
        8
    6
```

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: I ll upload it in the post now

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text but post text as text.

Comment: What is n in your example? Also you seem to be missing the concept of 'tree depth'.

Comment: your code is UB, as pretty_print_r1 should return int for all path and doesn't. you probably want to change its signature to return `void`.

Comment: @Jarod42 is it really UB as he doesn't use the return value? But anyway, yes, he should change it to void

Comment: for C++ yes, for C no AFAIR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do

```
void pretty_print_r1(const int* tree, std::size_t size, int parent, int indent)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i)
    {
        if (tree[i] == parent) {
            std::cout << std::string(indent, ' ') << i + 1 << std::endl;
            pretty_print_r1(tree, size, i + 1, indent + 4);
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c7e95859708aa4f)